# Не работает код в JavaScript файле

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

У меня такая проблема - когда я пишу данный кусочек кода в своём js файле, он не работает.
Но работает в теге

```html
<script>
```

```js
`Вот этот js код`
var counter = 0; // Переменная counter, значение 0
    $("#number").html(counter); //Строка кода для вывода числа
    function count(){ //Функция подсчёта
    counter = counter + 1; //Строка кода, добавляющая 1 цифру в переменной counter
    $("#number").html(counter); // Вывод полученного числа
    };
```

```html
<script> `Вот код, не рабочий в JS файле. Но тут он работает, в теге script`
    var counter = 0; // Переменная counter, значение 0
    $("#number").html(counter); //Строка кода для вывода числа
    function count(){ //Функция подсчёта
    counter = counter + 1; //Строка кода, добавляющая 1 цифру в переменной counter
    $("#number").html(counter); // Вывод полученного числа
};
</script>
```

Этот js код работает в моём html файле, а в js файле нет.
Почему - не знаю.
Прошу помочь.
Вот также скриншот экрана в VSCode -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот вывод кода в браузере -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s - И я использую JQuerry -

```
<script src="http://code.jquerry.com/jquerry-1.1.13.js> </script>
```

Вот код html файла -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sormio - tests</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="number" onclick="count();">
    </h1>
    <p>Это какой-то текст.</p>
</body>
<script>
    var counter = 0; // Переменная counter, значение 0
    $("#number").html(counter); //Строка кода для вывода числа
    function count(){ //Функция подсчёта
    counter = counter + 1; //Строка кода, добавляющая 1 цифру в переменной counter
    $("#number").html(counter); // Вывод полученного числа
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Фото с файлами -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы прикрпеляете js файл к index.html? Приложите содержание index.html полностью, пожалуйста

Comment: Вариантов не особо много. Вы либо не правильно подключаете файл скрипта, либо подключаете его до контента.

Comment: Добавил весь код - @reznikovkg

Comment: Проверил, всё правильно соединил, + все файлы я храню в 1 папке. Т.е, мои css, html и js файлы хранятся в 1 папке, поэтому их и легче соединять. И ссылка на jquerry тоже правильная. - @fortavey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш JS-код в файле обрабатывается до того как интепритатору известно о содержании `<body>`

Вам необходимо либо дожидаться полной загрузки страницы через `document.load` [читать тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

Ваш js файл

```
window.onload = function() {
    // ...код из вашего файла
};
```

Либо прикрепить сам файл в конце страницы внутри тега `<body>`

Вот так:

```
<body>
    ...
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Огромное вас спасибо, заработало! Я подключил свой js файл в конце тега body.